# How to use GPIO of raspberry pi in electron App?

Tags: node.js, electron, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to build an app for raspberry pi 3 (b) using electronJs. I am not able to use "[onoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff)" module of nodejs to communicate with GPIO of raspberry pi. When I import it in main process and try to run the app using `electron .` command, the command exits with no error info. Can anyone please suggest how to use GPIO of raspberry pi3 in electron App.

Also if its not possible with electronJs then please suggest how can I implement a GUI app for raspberry pi which can use GPIO.

Sample repo of same https://github.com/AkshayKanchan/electron_gpio

Comment: Without code it's impossible to guess what, if anything, is wrong. There are countless ways to implement a GUI + GPIO (and many examples and tutorials).

Comment: Added a sample repo of electron app. 
https://github.com/AkshayKanchan/electron_gpio
when I run this code through terminal, it just exits with no error log.
But when I run gpio code in simple nodejs file (without electron) it works very well.
And thank you for quick reply :)

Comment: So you’re asking why you Electron app doesn’t run, nothing to do with gpio?

Comment: If I just comment the require statement of "onoff" lib the code works as expected on raspberry pi. So I want to know if thats the correct way to use gpio in electron or am I making some mistake.

Comment: Also you did mention, there are countless ways to implement GUI+GPIO can you suggest some (using nodejs). I need to build a standalone app for raspberry pi 3 B.

Comment: You can search for RPi GUIs for some ideas. Re: Electron; I'll see if I can dupe the behavior.

Comment: Thank You! waiting for your response.

Comment: HI! have you tried? were you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Not yet, have other stuff to do. May get to it today, might not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating nodeJS to latest build and running [electron-rebuild](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules) solved my problem. Thank you Dave Newton for your help. Seems like there was an issue with epoll compilation which is used by [onoff](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onoff) package.

Answer (score 0):

1. First install Electron-Rebuild using npm install --save-dev
   electron-rebuild.
2. Then type npx electron-rebuild.
3. If it still doesn't work uninstall onoff module then install it again and
   then type npx electron-rebuild.
   Thats how it worked for me.